# mongoexport Error parsing command line: too many positional options

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

`bin]$ ./mongoexport --host xxxxxxxxx-2.xxxxxx-mongo.123.xxxxdbdns.com -d mydatabase -c my_locations -f "_id" --csv>locs.csv` doesn't work.

It gives me Error parsing command line: too many positional options.
Please help

Comment: Why are u using `./` while giving command? Try without using it. Also u can add password in command.

Comment: @Vishwas when I do that , it gives me ---mongoexport: command not found

Comment: The syntax is like `mongoexport --host hostname --password pwd --db dbName --collection collectionName  --type=csv --fields name,name2 --out fileName.csv`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should try the below, it should work:

```html
$ mongoexport --host xxxxxxxxx-2.xxxxxx-mongo.123.xxxxdbdns.com -d mydatabase -c my_locations -f _id --type=csv --out locs.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help at StackOverflow, but your question would probably be appreciated even more if you had augmented it with some explanation.